# Limpar 2 campos do tipo select ao preencher um determinado campo input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso limpar os valores preenchidos de 2 campos do tipo `select` quando preencher um campo do tipo `input`.

Ao preencher o campo `input` com nome `postcode` eu quero que os valores dos  campos do tipo `select` com nome `country_id` e `zone_id` sejam limpados para que seja necessário selecioná-los novamente.

Segue o meu código:

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="" placeholder="Coloque seu CEP" id="input-order-postcode" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
    <select name="country_id" id="input-order-country" class="form-control country-selector" data-post-code-required="#input-order-postcode" data-zone="#input-order-zone">
        <option value="" selected="selected"> --- Selecione o País --- </option>
        <option value="30">Brasil</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group required">
    <select name="zone_id" id="input-order-zone" class="form-control">
        <option value="" data-sigla='' selected="selected"> --- Selecione o Estado --- </option>
        <option value="440" data-sigla='AC'>Acre</option>
        <option value="441" data-sigla='AL'>Alagoas</option>
        <option value="442" data-sigla='AP'>Amapá</option>
        <option value="443" data-sigla='AM'>Amazonas</option>
        <option value="444" data-sigla='BA'>Bahia</option>
        <option value="445" data-sigla='CE'>Ceará</option>
        <option value="446" data-sigla='DF'>Distrito Federal</option>
        <option value="447" data-sigla='ES'>Espírito Santo</option>
        <option value="448" data-sigla='GO'>Goiás</option>
        <option value="449" data-sigla='MA'>Maranhão</option>
        <option value="450" data-sigla='MT'>Mato Grosso</option>
        <option value="451" data-sigla='MS'>Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
        <option value="452" data-sigla='MG'>Minas Gerais</option>
        <option value="453" data-sigla='PA'>Pará</option>
        <option value="454" data-sigla='PB'>Paraíba</option>
        <option value="455" data-sigla='PR'>Paraná</option>
        <option value="456" data-sigla='PE'>Pernambuco</option>
        <option value="457" data-sigla='PI'>Piauí</option>
        <option value="458" data-sigla='RJ'>Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="459" data-sigla='RN'>Rio Grande do Norte</option>
        <option value="460" data-sigla='RS'>Rio Grande do Sul</option>
        <option value="461" data-sigla='RO'>Rondônia</option>
        <option value="462" data-sigla='RR'>Roraima</option>
        <option value="463" data-sigla='SC'>Santa Catarina</option>
        <option value="464" data-sigla='SP'>São Paulo</option>
        <option value="465" data-sigla='SE'>Sergipe</option>
        <option value="466" data-sigla='TO'>Tocantins</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar assim:

```
$('input#input-order-postcode').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value) $('select').val('');
});
```

Isso faz com que a cada mudança do valor do input ele verifique de maneira simples se ele tem valor, e caso tenha faz com que os selects voltem à opção inicial.

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/3zL6c949/

Se quiseres ser mais específico nos eventos ou seletores em vêz de respectivamente `change` e de somente `select`.

Comment: Tem como especificar somente os 2 `select`?

Comment: @Wendell sim tem, podes usar `ID` e separar por virgulas assim: `$('#input-order-zone, #input-order-country').val('');`

Comment: Sergio, deu certo. O único problema é que é necessário clicar fora do `input` para que os campos `select` voltem para o estado inicial. Teria alguma forma disto ser feito sem ter que clicar fora do campo?

Comment: @Wendell sim, eu deixei um comentário sobre isso na resposta. Há eventos diferentes que podes usar, por exemplo `$('input#input-order-postcode').on('change, input, keyup', function() {`. Assim ele escuta 3 eventos, mas se não precisares de todos tira alguns.

Comment: Maravilha! Isto mesmo que precisa, obrigado.